# Two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that limit of $f(x)g(x)$ exists but individual limit doesn't

Tags: calculus

So, I have to come up with two functions such that their individual limit does not exist but the limit of the product exists. I came up with following examples of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
0 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases} $$

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x$ is rational} \\
1 & \text{if $x$ is irrational}
\end{cases} $$

such that the following limits do not exist.

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x) $$
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} g(x) $$

Since the functions oscillate between $1$ and $0$. But if we take their product, then we have
$h(x) = f(x)g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Being a constant function, we have

$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} h(x) = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} 0 = 0$$

So, the limit of the product of the functions is well defined.

Is this a good example ?

Comment: Yes, this works out.

Comment: Yes, it is a good example. You can also take $f(x)=0$ for all $x \geq 0$, $f(x)=1$ for all $x <0$ and $g(x)=1$ for all $x \geq 0$, $g(x)=0$ for all $x <0$.

Comment: You also can take $$f(x)=g(x)=\begin{cases}1&x\in\Bbb Q\\-1&x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}$$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(2+\sin x)\left(\frac1{2+\sin x}\right)=1$$

Comment: You can also take $\frac{1}{x}$ (for both $f,g,$). So the limit as $x \to 0$ exists but the individual doesn't